# Filling empty MySQL Result

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql5

I want to have a continuos date set with the sales.

```
SELECT *,
   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(calendar.datefield) * 1000 AS time,
   IFNULL(Sum(mos + mosnk), 0)               AS mosfinal,
   IFNULL(Sum(neukunden), 0)                 AS neukunden
FROM   sms_stats
   RIGHT JOIN calendar
           ON ( DATE(sms_stats.date) = calendar.datefield )
WHERE  calendar.datefield BETWEEN Curdate() - INTERVAL 90 day AND Now()
GROUP  BY Date_format(calendar.datefield, '%Y%m%d')
```

this returns me a list of the last 90 days. Now I want to filter it, but if I do

```
WHERE owner = 2 AND calendar.datefield BETWEEN Curdate() - INTERVAL 90 day AND Now()
```

it just returns one result and not the list of dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the `where` clause "undoes" the `right outer join`.  The solution is to move the condition to the `where` clause.  I have a preference for `left outer join` over `right outer join`, so I'll swap the tables:

```
SELECT *,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.datefield) * 1000        AS time,
       IFNULL(Sum(mos + mosnk), 0)               AS mosfinal,
       IFNULL(Sum(neukunden), 0)                 AS neukunden
FROM calendar c LEFT JOIN
     sms_stats ss
     ON DATE(ss.date) = c.datefield  and
        ss.owner = 2
WHERE c.datefield BETWEEN Curdate() - INTERVAL 90 day AND Now()
GROUP BY Date_format(c.datefield, '%Y%m%d') ;
```

I added in table aliases to make the query a bit more readable.

Comment: `calendar.datefield` needs to be `c.datefield` aswell. Thanks, it works!